# Нужно реверснуть массив из строк и при этом сохранить их длину

Tags: java

У меня есть на входе массив строк, мне нужно их все реверснуть но самое для меня сложное, это сохранить длину каждого объекта массива
Например:

```
Input:  {"Don't", "worry", ",", "be", "happy", "!"}
Output: {"!yppa", "heb,y", "r", "ro", "wt'no", "D"}
```

Код:

```
public class ArrayReverser {
  public static String[] reverse(String[] a) {
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      strBuilder.append(a[i]);
    }
    strBuilder.reverse();
    String newString = strBuilder.toString();
    int pos = 0;
    String[] b = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      int len = a[i].length();
      for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
        b[j] = newString.substring(pos, len);
      }
      pos = pos + len;
    } 
    return b;
  }  
}
```

Comment: А почему вы пишете заглавными буквами? Если опасаетесь, что вас не поймут, то просто пишите соблюдая правила правописания. Тогда вас поймут быстрее.

Comment: Исправил , если вам так режет глаз.

Comment: ну нужно так нужно. Даю добро на выполнение задания.

Answer (score 1):

Объединяете все слова в одну строку.

Обращаете её.

Записываете в выходной массив куски длинной строки с длинами, соответствующими длинам исходных коротких строк.

```
int pos = 0;
for(int i=0; i<a.length();i++) {
   int len = a[i].length();
   b[i] = Копировать из ReversedLongString с позиции pos количество символов len;
   pos += len;
}
```

На основе вашего последнего кода (проверить мне не на чем)

```
public class ArrayReverser {
  public static String[] reverse(String[] a) {
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      strBuilder.append(a[i]);
    }
    strBuilder.reverse();
    String newString = strBuilder.toString();
    int pos = 0;
    String[] b = new String[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      int len = a[i].length();
      b[i] = newString.substring(pos, pos + len);
      pos = pos + len;
    } 
    return b;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Прописал вроде бы все правильно но компилятор не пропускает в чем может быть проблема? Вот мой код:

Comment: public class ArrayReverser {
  public static String[] reverse(String[] a) {
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      strBuilder.append(a[i]);
    }
    strBuilder.reverse();
    String newString = strBuilder.toString();
    int pos = 0;
    String[] b = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      int len = a[i].length();
      for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
        b[j] = newString.substring(pos, len);
      }
      pos = pos + len;
    } 
    return b;
  }  
}

Comment: В комментариях код нечитабельный. Отредактируйте свой вопрос, в конец добавив код

Comment: спасибо поправил вопрос и вставил свой код в котором возникает ошибка

Comment: Длина b не задана. `String[] b = new String[a.length];` Цикл должен быть один, как у меня написано